# GridView Right Align CellTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, gridview

How do I get the TextBlock to be Right aligned

```
<GridViewColumn Width="45">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="#Doc" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap"  TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Text="{Binding Path=Count, StringFormat={}{0:N0}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

HorizontalContentAlignment and TextAlignment don't fix it (for me)

even tried and it did not fix it (for me)

```
<ListView.Resources>  
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">  
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />  
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: Your second option was working for me though. Can you show snapshot what it currently looks like with style in place?

Comment: @RohitVats Since it is a commercial app I cannot post an image but I will try and produce a simple app to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah that would be nice because i just tried in small sample and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [TextAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textalignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" ... />
```

Also, the binding for the `Text` property of `TextBlock` is `OneWay` by default, so you do not need to set it explicitly in the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

http://highfieldtales.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/hacking-the-wpf-gridview-two-more-features/

It's a series of posts by me on how to hack the GridView, and get some hidden gem from it.