# WPF - Can't right-align a TextBlock when using StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a TextBlock within a GridViewColumn. I format to currency using StringFormat. This causes the field to be left aligned. I can't get it right aligned. Tried HorizontalAlignment and TextAlignment but nothing works.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat={}{0:€ # ##0}}" />
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat={}{0:€ # ##0}}" />
```

If I do this [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052380/gridview-right-align-celltemplate), it works but right aligns all columns. I want numbers right aligned, dates centre and text left.

```
<ListView.Resources>  
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">  
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />  
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Any clues please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`. This will work:

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      </Style>
   </ListView.Resources>
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat={}{0:€ # ##0}}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: That does it nicely. Not sure if I understand why though. Thanks Joel too for same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your resource to HorizontalContentAlignment to Stretch, this will allow the contents of each cell in the ListView to take up the entire space. Then your HorizontalAlignment attributes will work.